# Декодирование экранированного XML

Tags: golang, soap, xmlparser

Пытаюсь распарсить вот такой SOAP:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns="http://www.aspentech.com/SQLplus.WebService/">
   <ExecuteSQLResult>
    &lt;NewDataSet&gt;
       &lt;Table&gt;
          &lt;Name&gt;Name.20&lt;/Name&gt;
       &lt;value&gt;-0.0014&lt;/value&gt;
       &lt;TS&gt;04-OCT-17 16:30:38.2&lt;/TS&gt;
       &lt;/Table&gt;
    &lt;/NewDataSet&gt;
   </ExecuteSQLResult>
  </ExecuteSQLResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Если вместо амперсантов проставлять руками < >, то парсит нормально:

https://goplay.space/#rAG6mKHeoTG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло использование html.UnescapeString

Answer (score 1):

У вас XML внутри XML, так что используйте двойное декодирование:

```golang
e := SOAPEnvelope{}
err := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data)).Decode(&e)
// Check err.

ds := DataSet{}
err = xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(e.Body.ExecuteSQLResponse.ExecuteSQLResult)).Decode(&ds)
// Check err.
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ds.Table)
//   {Name:Name.20 Value:-0.0014 TS:04-OCT-17 16:30:38.2}
```

Можно завернуть внутрь `UnmarshalXML`, если хотите, чтобы происходило автоматом.

Полный код примера: https://play.golang.org/p/LtuH-nIvUKP.